# Git poll setup for Jenkins groovy (scripted) pipeline

Tags: git, jenkins, groovy, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline

I'm trying to setup GIT poll for groovy pipeline. Scripted, not declarative

```
git branch: '${Branch}',
    credentialsId: 'some.key.ssh',
    poll: true,
    url: "ssh://git@bitbucket-ssh.company.com/project-${env.Project}.git"
```

*Git Branch is set from parameters*: [image: Parameterized Builds for Jenkins]
*Poll SCM is set to:* * * * * *
[image: Poll config]

I see that polling works - but it can't get anything - it doesn't trigger build
[image: Poll log]

So the question is - is there a way to fix that?
Please don't suggest webhooks - I can't use that. Only **Poll SCM**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Made it work with **GitSCM**

```
checkout([$class: 'GitSCM', 
     ranches: [[name: '*/master']], 
     doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false, 
     extensions: [], 
     submoduleCfg: [], 
     userRemoteConfigs: [[url: 'https://github.com/unickq/allure-nunit.git']]])
```

Snipplet Generator:

[image: Plugin in steps generator]

Answer (score 0):

In a Jenkinsfile you can use cron like so:

```
pipeline {
    agent { label "master" }

    triggers { 
        cron('* * * * *') 
    }
    .
    .
    .
}
```

Comment: That's great - but I use scripted pipeline and I don't need cron for this task